# Suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded divergent sequence. Let $S=$ range$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Can $S$ be an infinite set?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So $S$ is the set of all the terms of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. I feel like $S$ must be a finite set. I know that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ cannot be monotone,  since it's bounded and divergent. So if $S$ is infinite, then the terms of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ must be alternating  somehow without infinitely repeating or getting increasingly closer to some accumulation point, but does such a sequence even extist? I don't think so, but I can't seem to prove it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you defining the range?

Comment: @Mathmo123 $S$ is the range (the set of all the terms of the sequence).

Comment: Try the sequence 1, 1, 1, ½, 1, ⅓, 1, ¼, 1, 1/5, .... (i.e. alternate the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ with 1s)

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thanks. So $S$ can be infinite. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of Rational approximations to $\sqrt 2$ 
( or to any irrational number), i.e., $a_n$ is the first $n$ terms of the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$. This sequence diverges ( in $\mathbb Q$), but all terms are contained in the bounded interval $[1,2]$, and all terms are different.Also, as Mathmo suggested, you can weave together divergent sequences into a single sequence.